# Failed building wheel for uwsgi on mac silicon

Tags: macos, uwsgi, apple-m1, pyenv, rosetta-2

I'm trying to install uwsgi on mac with M1 arm processor using x86_64 architecture (rosetta 2). When I do this the installation fails with this stack:

[image]

I'm using pyenv with python 3.8.5

What's I'm doing wrong? Will be glad to give you more details on your requests. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the error running

```
brew install uwsgi
```

Then installation via pyenv also started to work